# Boolean recursion method

Tags: c#, recursion, boolean

So I have been trying to practice recursion so far and I got stuck.

I have to write a method that is type of `bool` and takes two parameters (array of ints, and int). The method itself should check if numbers in the array are bigger then 1000.

Depending on second parameter it should check only those numbers. So if array is `4, 5, 1001, 1003` and second parameter is `3` then only first 3 values in the array should be checked (`4,5,1001`). In this case it should return false because 4 and 5 are smaller then 1000. But if first 3 values were bigger then 1000, method should return true.

This is the leftovers of my method. I tried a lot before.
I am a bit confused how should it work with `Boolean`.

```
public bool sumofD(int [] x , int n)
{
    if (x[n] < 1000)
        { return false; }
    else
    {
        sumofD(x, n - 1);
        return true;
    }               
}
```

Comment: you want to `return sumofD(x, n -1)` surely? Here you're saying until `x[n] < 1000` keep executing `n-1`. A while loop would better suit this situation

Comment: I need to return true or false , but the method should be written recursively

Comment: You could use this more readable LINQ version: `bool allGreaterEqual1000 = x.Take(n-1).All(i => i >= 1000)`

Comment: It is recursive if it calls itself. That is the basics of recursion, the key things you need to look out for is making sure there is an end points, mainly by guarding your parameters. E.g. `if (n < 0) return;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter of course there are better solutions than a recursive method, but I think OP is specifically practising recursion, even if it's a bad exampe for recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good example for recursion as it would be easier to simply iterate throug the array.

Anyway, you forgot the end-condition for your recursion. You want to stop the recursion if `n < 0`:

```
public bool sumofD(int [] x , int n)
{
    // check if you already checked all values
    if (n <= 0) return true; 
    if (x[n - 1] < 1000) // use n-1
        { return false; }
    else
        // return if all the leading values are > 1000
        return sumofD(x, n - 2);
}
```

And your second mistake was to always `return true` no matter what your recursive call returned.

I changed the code that it returns the result of your recursive call, semantically meaing: "if the current value is greater than 1000, return the result of the check for the leading values".

---

**Update**: if `n` is the number of elements to check, you want to start at `x[n-1]` since arrays are 0-indexed. And change the other usages of `n` accordingly (checking `n <= 0` before and calling recursivly with `n-2`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work;

```
    public static bool sumofD(int[] x, int n)
    {
        n -= 1;
        if (n < 0) return true;
        return x[n] >= 1000 && sumofD(x, n - 1);
    }
```